# Parse a malformed CSV line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, fastercsv

I am parsing the following CSV lines. I need to rescue malformed lines that look like `"Malformed"` below. What is a regular expression I can use to do this? What considerations do I need to make?

```
body = %(
"Sensitive",2416,159,"Test "Malformed" Failure",2789,111,7-24-11,1800,0600,"R2","12323","",""
"Sensitive",2742,107,"Test",2791,112,7-24-11,1800,0600,"R1","","",""
"Sensitive",2700,135,"Test",2792,113,7-24-11,1800,0600,"R1","12110","","")

rows = []
body.each_line do |line|
  begin
    rows << FasterCSV.parse_line(line)
  rescue FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError => e
    rows << line if rescue_from_malformed_line(line)
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error(e.to_s)
    Rails.logger.info(line)
  end
end
```

Comment: What action would you want to take with a line like that? I would suggest splitting at the ,'s and removing the quotes then reconstructing the correct csv and resuming on the next line.

Comment: I would like to include the double quotes in the array of ararys.

Comment: Might the misquoted text contain a comma? Why not pre-process the CSV file off-line before feeding it to your application, instead of having to fix it each time you have to read it?

Comment: Won't preprocessing *and then* passing it to FasterCSV be more expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how malformed your data is malformed, but here is one approach for that line.

```
> puts line
"Sensitive",2416,159,"Test "Malformed" Failure",2789,111,7-24-11,1800,0600,"R2","12323","",""
>
> puts line.scan /[\d.-]+|(?:"[^"]*"[^",]*)+/
"Sensitive"
2416
159
"Test "Malformed" Failure"
2789
111
7-24-11
1800
0600
"R2"
"12323"
""
""
```

**Note**: Tested on ruby 1.9.2p290

Comment: Hey this splits the date as well, try using `line.split ","`

Comment: @Devin, I didn't realized that there were dates, fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Np, just noticed it by chance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to replace the nested double quotes with single quotes before it's passed to the parser.

Something like

```
.gsub(/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/,"'")
```